# Inaccurate filtering results in my AngularJS application

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having some issues with filtering data in my program.

The foll is my JSON sample:

```
  {
"expression": "to the day",
"meaning": "",
"example": "it's been four years to the day.",
"pronunciation": "",
"notes": "",
"meta": {
"book": [""],
"author": [""],
"tags": ["music"]}
},
```

The problem that i am facing is as follows: If i were to select a particular tag/author from the Tags/Author dropdown, the results are getting narrowed down as expected; however, when i click the 'Clear' button, the content disappears. I have to refresh the page for all the results to be displayed again.

I have another application using the same logic and in that clicing the 'Clear' button does not lead to the results disappearing. So i'm a bit concerned as to why it's working in one instance and not in the other.

I'd appreciate if you can help me understand where i'm going wrong here.
The foll is the code of my Tags and Authors dropdwon:

```
<md-input-container>
<label>Tags</label>
<md-select ng-model="tag">
<md-option ng-repeat="tag in tags | orderBy: 'toString()'" value="{{ tag }}"> <!-- tags here refers to a newly defined array that stores only one instance of all the tags against the 'tags' property on each object/word -->
{{ tag }} 
</md-option>
</md-select>
</md-input-container>

<md-input-container>
            <label>Authors</label>
            <md-select ng-model="author">
                <md-option ng-repeat="author in authors | orderBy: 'toString()'" value="{{ author }}"> <!-- authors here refers to a newly defined array that stores only one instance of all the authors against the 'author' property on each object/word -->
                    {{ author }} 
                </md-option>
            </md-select>
</md-input-container>
```

The foll is the code in my Clear button:

```
<md-input-container>
            <md-button class="md-warn" ng-click="classifiedsFilter = ''; tag = ''; book = ''; author = ''; order = ''  ">Clear</md-button>
        </md-input-container>
```

The foll is my fitler logic:

```
<md-card ng-repeat="classified in classifieds | filter: classifiedsFilter | filter: {meta: {tags: tag}} | filter: {meta: {'book': book}} | filter: {meta: {'author': author}} | orderBy: order" flex-xs="100" flex-sm="40" flex-gt-sm="30" class="classified">
```

Comment: can you post a fiddle ?

Comment: One major bug is you are breaking the cardinal rule of always using an object in `ng-model`. Primitives don't have inheritance in child scopes

Comment: @charlietfl so what's the alternative?

Comment: Alternative to what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding too many filter add a single object(filterParams as shown below) which holds the properties to be filtered>>>

```
<md-card ng-repeat="classified in classifieds | filter:filterParams | orderBy: order" flex-xs="100" flex-sm="40" flex-gt-sm="30" class="classified">
```

all your select elements should use filterParams object as ng-model, for instance if you want to filter based on author use "filterParams.author" as ng-model>>

```
<md-select ng-model="filterParams.author">
                <md-option ng-repeat="author in authors | orderBy: 'toString()'" value="{{ author }}"> <!-- authors here refers to a newly defined array that stores only one instance of all the authors against the 'author' property on each object/word -->
                    {{ author }} 
                </md-option>
            </md-select>
```

in your controller, initialise filterParams>>

```
$scope.filterParams ={} //initially no filters
```

your cancel action should reset the filterParams object

```
<md-input-container>
            <md-button class="md-warn" ng-click="filterParams={} ">Clear</md-button>
        </md-input-container>
```

What went wrong in your example? while assigning empty string to all the filters on clicking clear, filter action happens and only empty value is shown that explains why the blank page. Then while you refresh, the filter gets cleared. If you use an object as shown in  my example, then the code becomes cleaner and easy to manage.

Comment: thanks MM.. im gonna refactor my code, and shout you an update. however, im not quite sure i understand the foll. can i request you to pls break it down for me coz i wld really like to understand why my code is malfucntioning: `What went wrong in your example? while assigning empty string to all the filters on clicking clear, filter action happens and only empty value is shown that explains why the blank page. Then while you refresh, the filter gets cleared. `

Comment: ok.. you were using `filter: {meta: {'book': book}}` which means filter the list based on the value stored in the variable book. So if you do something like book = ' ', it means filter the list where book is having the value ' '. your list will not have any book named ' ', which will result in a blank page. In short you are not clearing the filter, you were assigning a  blank value to the filter

Comment: aahh.. yes.. that explanation was really helpful.. now i atleast haev a handle on why it's not working... thanks MM... i will refactor my code per your suggestion and i will let you know if it works

Comment: i implemented your suggestion in the code... but now its not filtering with any of the properties, for instances, tags, book, or author. the foll is a snippet of my controller: `$scope.classifieds.$loaded().then(function(classifieds) {

   $scope.filterParams = {};
   $scope.tags = getTags(classifieds); // call the getTags method below
   $scope.books = getBooks(classifieds); // call the getBooks method below
   $scope.authors = getAuthors(classifieds); // call the getAuthors method below
   $scope.order = ""; 
  });`

Comment: Update: so when i implement the filters in the template as follows the filtering does not work: `<md-card ng-repeat="classified in classifieds | filter: classifiedsFilter | filter: filterParams |orderBy: order"  class="classified">` however, when i implement it as follows, the results are getting narrowed as expected, and upon clicking 'clear' the results do not disappear: `<md-card ng-repeat="classified in classifieds | filter: classifiedsFilter | filter: filterParams.tag | filter: filterParams.book | filter: filterParams.author |orderBy: order" flex-xs="100"  class="classified">`

Comment: @Nosail that looks great